# Using a Delegate with a TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a TabBarController which is set up with multiple ViewControllers at launch.  When the user clicks a button I want to send them to a different ViewController in the TabBarController, and pass data through a delegate.

I have a protocol and delegate set up.  However, when do you set the delegate since all the ViewControllers are in the TabBarController

Is this possible, how can I pass data to another ViewController in the TabBar when the user clicks a button.  Any ideas, I'd really like to use a delegate.

```
- (IBAction)sendData:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate setStringData:strData];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Edit:

So let's say I have a TabBarController with two ViewControllers called ViewControllerOne and ViewControllerTwo.

I have ViewControllerTwo set up as the delegate and protocol.  This is the ViewController that will send data to ViewControllerOne after the button is pressed.  ViewControllerOne implements  protocol and contains the method setStringData which should be called after the button in ViewControllerTwo is pressed.

Comment: please, use some subjects... which class should be the delegate? and in which class should it be used? you are going to go from a viewController to another... then?

Comment: I'll edit to make it a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution to my problem.  Inside of ViewControllerTwo, I just create an instance of ViewControllerOne and pass it that data I need. Then I change the tabBarController index to ViewControllerOne.

For example:

```
// A method inside of ViewControllerTwo
ViewController *viewcontrollerOne = [ViewcontrollerOne alloc] init];
[viewcontrollerOne setStringData:str];
[viewcontrollerOne release];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From a UIViewController you want to change the selected tab bar index and pass data.
I suggest you add a function in you app delegate for this.
That way your UIViewController won't be tied with a UITabBar (if tomorrow you want to use a different UI idiom, you will just have to change the implementation of your function in your app delegate).

To pass data, i you could try to introspection in your function : you take the current UIViewController of the new selected tab index, verify it responds to your selector and call the function.

Edit :

Let's assume your 'just' have to change the selected tabBar index (e.g. your UIViewController will always be the same on the new tab bar index).

In your first View Controller :

```
    - (IBAction)sendData:(id)sender
    {
        UIApplicationDelegate * appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if ([appDelegate respondToSelector:@selector(goToFirstTabBarWithData:)])
        {
            [appDelegate performSelector:@selector(goToFirstTabBarWithData:) withObject: strData];
        }
    }
```

In your Appdelegate :

```
    - (void)goToFirstTabBarWithData:(NSString *)data
    {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
        UIViewController * vc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([vc respondToSelector:@selector(setStringData:)])
        {
            [vc performSelector:@selector(setStringData:) withObject:data];
        }
    }
```

In your second View controller (the one you will arrive on) :

```
    - (void)setStringData:(NSString *)data
    {
        // Do something...
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand this answer.  So this method is in the AppDelegate?  There is no delegate and protocol now?  Assuming I won't change my UI idiom, could you simplify this?

Comment: And the setStringData method, where would that be located?

Comment: You need to have this code in to your tabbar controller and implement those method in your view controller.

Comment: I've edited my reply to show you the full implementation. As i said, i  assume you will always have the same UIViewController subclass at the newly selected tab bar index.

Comment: One more question I want to go from ViewControllerTwo to ViewControllerOne  so I will call setStringData in ViewController one, and call sendData in ViewControllerTwo. Is that right or do I have that wrong?

Comment: Well you could, but it's better (in my opinion) to separate correctly your logic, which means you'll send your data to the fonction of the appDelegate, as you can see in my example. Your button in ViewController 2 wants to show the user another controller with 'data'. It calls the AppDelegate who is responsible to show the correct ViewController. This AppDelegate select the tabBar index and send the data to the newly selected View controller. Is this reply correct for you or do i miss one of your requirement ?